# Unity Best way to overwrite `StandardAssetsScripts`

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input

I am Developing a FPS Game and I am using The `FPSController` that comes with the Standard Assets. I am developing a Gamepad controller to control the mobile game.

After configuring all inputs of the controller I want to replace the code as following:

```
if (!m_Jump)
{
   m_Jump = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump");
}
```

The code should be like following:

```
if(Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
{
    if (!m_Jump)
    {
        m_Jump = Input.GetButtonDown("Joystick A");
    }
}else{
    if (!m_Jump)
    {
        m_Jump = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump");
    }
}
```

> What is the best way to modify the `FPS Controller` Scripts and add These Inputs?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You can go around this in a way that does not require you to edit or add any aditional code.

Under Edit>Project Settings > Input you can find the InputManager and "axis". In here you will find all the pre-defined input values and their corresponding buttons. If you unfold the Input Axis "Jump" You'll see it has a variable called "Positive button" which is by default space, and an empty "alternative button". If you add your desired button to the alternative button sectiong it will trigger the `CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump");`  action upon pressing the corresponding button on your gamepad.

you can also if you prefer extend the list and add your own triggers.

The input manager offers out of the box support for keyboard and mouse, joystick, and gamepad more information can be found in the docs [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ConventionalGameInput.html)

The advantage of doing this is that this requires no additional code or conditions. Which is probably the most optimalised way to go aroung it